# mysql replace returns a NULL value for a longtext column

Tags: mysql

I have a column of type longtext (*contenu_fr*) and contains some long texts (>600Kb per row), when I use replace function it returns null.

```
select  REPLACE(contenu_fr, '<p>', '+') rr, contenu_fr
from `jo_article` where id=28200
```

how is this possible, knowing that replace never return a null if the original value isn't null.

**COLUMN CONTENENT CIPHERED**
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/seddik/3993e28d7a541bc500c15d047ab0f78d/raw/687361cf7ee4f9e310c29354281584e99056f4c2/sql%2520replace

**SCREENSHOT RESULT**

---

[image]

Comment: 1) Post code, not pics of code.  2)  Does the id exist?

Comment: @WillardSolutions of course the id exists, it is returning a value !

Comment: Just to discard the issue is in your IDE, can you reproduce the issue with other MySQL clients, such as the official command-line utility?

Comment: @seddik Of course, I suggest you read this, and then try your question again: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I've added some screen shots, its not an IDE problem, because my php code returns null too.

Comment: ```jo_article``` is different from ```joarticles``` :-?

Comment: I have a duplicated database, resulting the same problem, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating your content (HTML string) and copy pasted your query. REPLACE() is working as intended. I used MySQL 5.6.

Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eccb4a/1

Can you test your query there?

Comment: I couldn't get that working, it is a long string about (100Ko) the sqlfiddle returns error

Comment: here is the content of my column https://gist.githubusercontent.com/seddik/3993e28d7a541bc500c15d047ab0f78d/raw/687361cf7ee4f9e310c29354281584e99056f4c2/sql%2520replace

Comment: I truncated your sample but the REPLACE function returns a string, not NULL. on your example, you used column name contenu_fr the first time and contenu the second time. Is this a typo or are both valid?

Comment: yes the two are valid, when I added screenshots I used by mistake another table, but both exists